# How to prevent Next js app from caching my fetch call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, cache-control

In my nextJS app, I am using fetch API which collects data from mongoDB to fetch a list of participants.

In local developing environment, and production with Netlify it works well.

But in local production, and when I hosted on Vercel, it grams that are only on first call. Irrespective of I refreshes the page the data is not changed I have passed

`{cache: no-cache}`
inside `fetch` but no luck. I also tried `revalidate` as well. Can't find why. If it is something because of production the result would be similar in Netlify

I am giving associated lines of codes here. But I can share my GitHub repository link if needed more context

```
const [participants, setParticipants]  = useState([]);

  const fetchParticipants = async () => {

    try {

      const fetchedParticipants = await fetchAllParticipants();

      fetchedParticipants.sort((a, b) => a.serial - b.serial);

      setParticipants(fetchedParticipants);

    } catch (error) {

      console.log(error);

    }

  };

  // const [participant, setParticipant] = useState<IndexState['participant']>('')

  useEffect(() => {

    fetchParticipants();

  }, []);
```

actions/index.js

```
export const fetchAllParticipants = async () => {

  try {

    const response = await fetch("api/participants/all", {

      cache: 'no-cache', // don't cache

    });

    const data = await response.json();

    //console.logdata.allParticipants, " are all participants");

    return data.allParticipants;

  } catch (error) {

    console.log(error);

  }

};
```

app/api/participants/all/route.js

```
import connectToDb from '@utils/connectToDb'

import Participant from '@models/Participant'

export const GET = async () => {

    try {

        await connectToDb()

        const allParticipants = await Participant.find()

        // console.log(allParticipants, ' inside GET')

        return new Response(JSON.stringify({allParticipants,success: true, status: 200}))

        

    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error, ' error in route GET');

        return new Response(JSON.stringify({error}), {success: false, status:405})

    }

}
```

Please assist in finding what cause this.

I used next js 13.8 and 14 but they are not having any difference.

Thanks in advance

tried passing cache related options in fetch but got no result.

On searching internet I haven't found this problem discussed.

Comment: I exported const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' inside all/route.js. now it's fine everywhere. But still I have that doubt why Netlify haven't cached on production?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

^ Add this to the top of your route.ts

Comment: Yes this worked as I posted on comment. Buy netlify was not caching even without this on production